# The arrow in the input type date field doesn't disappear on selecting a valid value

Tags: html, css

My form looks like this

[image: Form]

I've managed to style the -webkit-calendar-picker-indicator button using a few webkit controls, and I've managed to get it on the entire date field. Now I want that as soon as I select a date, the width of this calendar picker indicator button reduces to 1% and opacity becomes 0%.

I believe using the right selectors I can make it possible. I want to do it using html and css only.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                margin: 0;
            }
            .formshadow{
                position: relative;
                color: white;
                margin:0 auto;
                background-color: #242424;
                height: 600px;
                width: 600px;
            }
            .form{
                color:#242424;
                position: absolute;
                margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
                padding:0;
                width: 600px;
                height: 600px;
                background-color: #9BE1EE;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family:"Segoe UI Light";
            }
            .formborder{
                position:relative;
                width: 530px;
                height: 530px;
                margin:32px auto;
                border:3px #242424 solid;
            }
            .formborder h1{
                display: block;
                font-size: 2em;
                -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
                -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
                -webkit-margin-start: 0;
                -webkit-margin-end: 0;
            }
            #dob::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
            #mobile::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
                display:none;
                -webkit-appearance:none;
            }
            #dob::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
                    width:100%;
                    height:42px;
                    opacity:1;
                    margin-left:-20px;
                    background-color:red;
            }
            #forminput{
                margin-left:60px;
                display:inline-block;
                position:relative;
                width:173px;
            }
            .form label{
                position: absolute;
                left:0;
                top:10;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            .form input{
                position:relative;
                line-height:50px;
                font-size:25px;
                background-color:transparent;
                border:none;
                border-bottom:1px #242424 solid;
                margin-bottom:8px;
            }
            input[type=number],input[type=date]{
                width:184px;
            }
            input:hover + label{
                position: absolute;
                left:0;
                top:0;
                font-size: 12px;
                transition:ease-in 0.2s;
            }
            input:focus + label{
                position: absolute;
                left:0;
                top:0;
                font-size: 12px;
                transition:ease-in 0.2s;
            }
            input:valid + label{
                position: absolute;
                left:0;
                top:0;
                font-size: 12px;
                transition:ease-in 0.2s;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="formshadow">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="formborder">
                    <center><h1>Registeration</h1></center>
                    <form>
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="10"/><label for="fname">First Name:</label></div>
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="10"/><label for="lname">Last Name:</label></div><br />
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="text" name="city" id="city" size="10"/><label for="city">City:</label></div>
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="text" name="state" id="state" size="10"/><label for="state">State:</label></div><br />
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="text" name="college" id="college" size="10"/><label for="college">College:</label></div>
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="text" name="id" id="id" size="10"/><label for="id">ID:</label></div><br />
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="number" name="mobile" id="mobile" size="10"/><label for="mobile">Mobile:</label></div>
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="email" name="email" id="email" size="10"/><label for="email">Email:</label></div><br />
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="date" name="dob" id="dob" size="10"/><label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label></div>
                        <div id="forminput"><input required type="text" name="occupation" id="occupation" size="10"/><label for="occupation">Occupation:</label></div><br />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your existing html and css.

You can do this.

```
#dob:valid::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
     display: none;
}
```

The idea is simple, you just need to check if the input is valid, 
then target the arrow and hide it.

This is tested, and will hide the arrow, the red background, etc.
What remains is the label and the actual date on your form.